# How to view combined (overlaid) Google Map's map and satellite view?

Tags: google-maps

There's "Sattellite/Map" button which toggles between map-only and satellite-only modes. How to view satellite image with the map (roads and rivers) drawn on top?

Comment: I actually see roads already overlaid by default. But not rivers...

Comment: I need Belarus.

Comment: @pnuts, maps-for-free shows the same as Google Maps. It also allows selecting only "Map" or "Satellite", not both.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Maps it is a choice of Map view or Satellite view and not one on top of the other (except possibly for a small part of the screen where one view replaces the other, which might be considered as "on top").

Comment: Already workarounded by making two screenshots and combining them in graphics editor.